# Why Labview is used in some t-f studies of HRV?

Tags: matlab, labview, cardio

I am studying [J. Schesser](https://web.njit.edu/~joelsd/)'s [work](http://biomedical.njit.edu/people/schesser.php) about HRV in ECG signals. 
I am waiting for his answer to the case but also others' opinions and reviews. He has used Labview in most of his ECG data analysis. 
I am thinking why, since much of my known electronics do not limit me there. I can use Matlab too. 
I want to study time and frequency domains in HRV analysis of ECG signals. 
I am mostly using Analog.com's electronics in my ECG boards and systems so they should not be limited to proprietary frontends like Labview.

Why Labview is used in some analysis parts of HRV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is mostly for NI's LabVIEW Biomedical Toolkit
http://sine.ni.com/nips/cds/view/p/lang/en/nid/211023

Comment: So do yourself what is the problem? You can write a google website as well. But you use google.com